# How to get dimension of shapes created in Html 5 Canvas

Tags: html, canvas

I want to know is there any way i can get width, height of a shape created in canvas? example:-

```
 var theCanvas = document.getElementById("canvasOne");
 var context = theCanvas.getContext("2d");

 context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(170, 80);
  context.bezierCurveTo(130, 100, 130, 150, 230, 150);
  context.bezierCurveTo(250, 180, 320, 180, 340, 150);
  context.bezierCurveTo(420, 150, 420, 120, 390, 100);
  context.bezierCurveTo(430, 40, 370, 30, 340, 50);
  context.bezierCurveTo(320, 5, 250, 20, 250, 50);
  context.bezierCurveTo(200, 5, 150, 20, 170, 80);

  // complete custom shape
  context.closePath();
  context.lineWidth = 5;
  context.strokeStyle = 'blue';
  context.stroke();
```

Now i want to access the dimension (width and height) of above created shape so that i can clear this shape only and then redraw it. I do not want to Clear whole Canvas.

I want something similar, like in case of image ( i can access its width and height):-

```
            pointImage = new Image();
            pointImage.src = "stone.png";
            image_x = (theCanvas.width - pointImage.width) / 2;
            image_y = (theCanvas.height - pointImage.height) / 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply clear the shape and redraw it. The canvas does not recognize your shape as an object and does not keep any data specific to that shape only. If you want to draw only on top of the specific region, then you would have to store region coordinates of your shape. Clearing it would be equivalent to filling the region with the background color, but this would work only if you have overlapping shapes or if the background is an image. Then redrawing it would work the same way you drew it the first time.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i am plannin to use co-ordinates to draw a hidden rect behind shape and then clear that rect.

Answer (score 1):

**Believe it or not!**

The concept of html canvas is to clear the entire screen and redraw every individual graphic component back on the screen again.  Seems wasteful, but canvas handles this by drawing **really fast**.

Let’s say you compose a scene where there is a background image and your white fulffy cloud.

[image]

Then you want to make fluffy cloud into a raincloud.

[image]

What you would do is:

Erase the entire canvas containing the white fluffy cloud:

```
context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
```

Redraw the background image of sky and grass:

```
context.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
```

And finally redraw the cloud with a rainy fill instead of white fill

```
context.moveTo(170, 80);
context.bezierCurveTo(130, 100, 130, 150, 230, 150);
context.bezierCurveTo(250, 180, 320, 180, 340, 150);
context.bezierCurveTo(420, 150, 420, 120, 390, 100);
context.bezierCurveTo(430, 40, 370, 30, 340, 50);
context.bezierCurveTo(320, 5, 250, 20, 250, 50);
context.bezierCurveTo(200, 5, 150, 20, 170, 80);
context.closePath();
context.lineWidth = 5;
context.strokeStyle = 'blue';
context.fillStyle=”gray”;
context.stroke();
context.fill();
```

To make your scene reusable, you would wrap your redraws into a function.

**This is why you usually don't need the coordinates of your cloud.**

You simply put the code that draws the cloud into a function and call that function each time you want to redraw your cloud.

```
function redraw(fill){
  context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  context.beginPath();
  // redraw the background image
  context.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  // redraw the cloud
  context.moveTo(170, 80);
  context.bezierCurveTo(130, 100, 130, 150, 230, 150);
  ...
  ...
  context.fill();
}
```

BTW, if you *really do want to know the bounding rectangle* of your cloud, you can use `context.getImageData`.  This will give you the rgba color of every pixel on your canvas. To find the left boundary you just start checking with the leftmost column of pixels for your blue cloud.  If you don't find blue, move onto the second column of pixels and check for blue.  When you do find a blue pixel in a column:  that's the left X coordinate of your cloud!

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Yze44/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=function(){
        redraw("transparent");
    }
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/skyGrass.png";


    function redraw(fill){
      context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
      context.beginPath();
      // redraw the background image
      context.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
      // redraw the cloud
      context.moveTo(170, 80);
      context.bezierCurveTo(130, 100, 130, 150, 230, 150);
      context.bezierCurveTo(250, 180, 320, 180, 340, 150);
      context.bezierCurveTo(420, 150, 420, 120, 390, 100);
      context.bezierCurveTo(430, 40, 370, 30, 340, 50);
      context.bezierCurveTo(320, 5, 250, 20, 250, 50);
      context.bezierCurveTo(200, 5, 150, 20, 170, 80);

      // complete custom shape
      context.closePath();
      context.lineWidth = 5;
      context.strokeStyle = 'blue';
      context.fillStyle=fill;
      context.stroke();
      context.fill();
      console.log(fill);
    }

    $("#light").click(function(){ redraw("white"); })
    $("#dark").click(function(){ redraw("gray"); })

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=420 height=300></canvas><br>
    <button id="light">Redraw as Light Cloud</button>
    <button id="dark">Redraw as Dark Cloud</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 for detailed explanation. But there are situations where clear the entire screen and redraw all again will be very expensive. Imagine a high resolution canvas in a low end device that's need to update only tiny portions of the canvas in a loop section like a game, for instance. In that case redraw the entire canvas every frame kills performance.

Comment: @gfcarv: very true--that info is in the html-canvas 102 class!  :)

Comment: It's not at all wasteful if you having a moving scene/background. You will have to redraw anyway. This is particularly where canvas excels:-)

Answer (score 0):

different ideas that you guys shared, i figure out a solution, that works for me. i am mentioning here so that other can improve it.

- Draw a Shape
- Keep track of its co-ordinates
- Use these Co-ordinates to draw a hidden rectangle around the Shape (optional)
- Now use clear.Rect() to clear the rectangle.  :-)

Sample:-

```
            context.strokeStyle = '#fff';
            context.strokeRect(130, 15, 300, 165);
```

This will make a rectangle around the shape. now i will clear this rect using:-

```
context.clearRect(130, 15, 300, 165);
```

this will clear only this region Not whole Canvas